# Canon MX 920 prints color even though I specify grayscale

Tags: drivers, printing, proprietary-drivers

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and installed drivers for Canon MX 920 according to the instructions, [Canon Drivers for Ubuntu and Linux Mint](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/canon-drivers-for-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/).

I can print things from Ubuntu to the Canon but my problem is, no matter how many places I specify "Grayscale", it still prints color.

This is frustrating and wastes lot of colored ink.

Is this a bug? What is the workaround to this?

I don't know how to tell which program I am using, here is a screenshot of when I open Canon

[image]

And just now, I called Canon Tech Support, 1-800-OK-CANON, and the lady said I can install one of the drivers from http://usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx922#DriversAndSoftware, but they cannot tell me which driver to download, nor help me go through the process.

If you can tell me which driver to download, I believe this will help greatly

[image]

Comment: What program(s) do you use for printing?

Comment: @Braiam I'll get the exact name of program soon

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Sorrily, I see after more testing that while the below settings can do the job, the solution is not too convenient because the settings are not remembered... It can still be used as a last resort...

---

In Linux Mint Xfce 19.1 with a HP OfficeJet printer I had problems in setting monochrome/grayscale printing.

In printer's properties, "Printer options", the "Color mode" setting shows only the option "color".

At "Job options" - "Other options" there is a "print-color-mode" settings with two options, "color" and "monochrome", but it would go back to default "color" when trying to change and save the other option.

I have found a solution that works [here](https://harbhag.wordpress.com/2010/07/03/enable-grayscale-printing-in-canon-pixma-mp250-series-on-ubuntu/), initially suggested in a discussion [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354789&p=13617040#post13617040). (Those instructions were for Canon, I tested them with HP).

In *System - Printers*, selecting the printer's properties, going to "Job options" - "Other options", down at the end there is an empty field to add a new option; fill that field with ***CNGrayscale*** and click "Add".

The new option is now listed under "Other options", but has an empty field: fill that with ***TRUE***, then click "Apply".

[image]

Now the new option *CNGrayscale* has a true/false switch that you can use to change between color and monochrome printing.

---

This seems to be related to availability or correct selection of drivers. Printers connect in different ways, and drivers can be selected automatically or manually. A solution might be to try adding the printer manually in a way that gives choice between different drivers that can be in this way tested.

For example, in my case, I was able to add the proper driver by connecting my wifi HP Officejet 3833 printer by USB cable to my internet modem/wifi box then, following [this method that is specific to my internet provider](https://www.freenews.fr/freenews-edition-nationale-299/tutoriels-172/mettre-une-imprimante-en-reseau-avec-la-freebox-6750) I have added new printer, selected *Network printer > AppSocket/HP JetDirect*, then entered my provider-specific data under *Location of the network printer - Host:*, then, selecting a driver from the database, I have selected HP; all Officejet numbers 3830 to 3834 had the same three drivers available:

[image]

The first in the list, which is marked 'recommended' was the one selected the last time and which entailed the very problem I was trying to solve. So, I have now selected the second one, the one that says `hpcups` (the printer being HP). (The third is `hpijs`; both come from HP and are based on `hplip`, as said [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2013-July/270541.html).)

In this way I have added the printer which, under *Properties > Printer options > Color mode*, now shows, beside *Color*, another two Grayscale options (High quality and Black only).

Comment: CNGrayscale does absolutely nothing for me.

Comment: @Calmarius - this is too old, you should post a new Q