# How can I print in greyscale in KDE Plasma applications?

Tags: kde, printing, plasma, plasma5

When I print in Plasma applications, such as Gwenview, I can select `Grayscale` instead of `Color` (see screenshot below). However, this doesn't do anything; images are always printed in colour. In contrast, I can print in greyscale in Firefox and Inkscape by selecting `Print Color as Gray` = `On` using their native print dialogue (perhaps GTK?). Hence, I presume that there is an issue specific to the KDE Plasma print dialogue box. Is there a way to print in greyscale in Gwenview?

[image: Gwenview print dialogue]

(Originally posted [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=213&t=138834&p=375773#p375773) with no answer.)

Comment: `I can print in greyscale in Firefox ... by selecting Print Color as Gray = On using their native print dialogue (perhaps GTK?)` - Where is that color option in the Firefox printing options? I only see [this](https://pasteboard.co/IksDzEe.png) and [this](https://pasteboard.co/IksDPS1.png).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorrily, I see after more testing that while the below settings (adding *CNGrayscale*) can do the job, the solution is not too convenient because the change is not remembered... It can still be used as a last resort...

---

I have tested this in Xfce, not in KDE. Initially posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525809/341192).

In *System - Printers*, selecting the printer's properties, going to "Job options" - "Other options", down at the end there is an empty field to add a new option; fill that field with ***CNGrayscale*** and click "Add".

The new option is now listed under "Other options", but has an empty field: fill that with ***TRUE***, then click "Apply".

[image]

Now the new option *CNGrayscale* has a true/false switch that you can use to change between color and monochrome printing.

---

This seems to be related to availability or correct selection of drivers. Printers connect in different ways, and drivers can be selected automatically or manually. A solution might be to try adding the printer manually in a way that gives choice between different drivers that can be in this way tested.

For example, in my case, I was able to add the proper driver by connecting my wifi HP Officejet 3833 printer by USB cable to my internet modem/wifi box then, following [this method that is specific to my internet provider](https://www.freenews.fr/freenews-edition-nationale-299/tutoriels-172/mettre-une-imprimante-en-reseau-avec-la-freebox-6750) I have added new printer, selected *Network printer > AppSocket/HP JetDirect*, then entered my provider-specific data under *Location of the network printer - Host:*, then, selecting a driver from the database, I have selected HP; all Officejet numbers 3830 to 3834 had the same 3 drivers available:

[image]

The first in the list, which is marked 'recommended' was the one selected the last time and which entailed the very problem I was trying to solve. So, I have now selected the second one, the one that says 'hpcups' (the printer being HP).

The third is `hpijs`; these two drivers come from HP and are based on `hplip`, as said [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2013-July/270541.html), but when testing both I see differences in the printer properties' interfaces: the `hpijs` driver doesn't have a color settings under "Printer options", and changes of the one under "Jop Options - Other options (Advanced)" are not remembered. So, `hpcups` is the good one for me.

In this way I have added the printer which, under *Properties > Printer options > Color mode*, now shows, beside *Color*, another two Grayscale options (High quality and Black only).

So, **this seems a driver issue**.

3.17 version worked for me, but there is also a newer version of the driver that can be installed like in the askubuntu answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/925128), redirecting to the HP page [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/install/index).

Comment: Thank you for posting! In KDE I can find a similar looking pane via Print Settings > Right-click on the printer > Properties > Job Options. However, after following the instructions as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/9vboijB.png), it's still printing in colour. I tried restarting the systemd units `org.cups.cupsd.service` and `cups-browsed.service`, but that didn't help. Also, do you have to open this dialog every time you want to toggle it back? I didn't find any option in the normal print dialog.

Comment: I guess I was lucky. See more links on various solutions at the address that pointed the way for me [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354789&p=13617040#post13617040).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I had a read through, but there wasn't much else that was relevant, I don't think, because I *can* print in greyscale in some situations, e.g. Firefox, but just not from KDE applications. So I don't think it's a general printing issue. I don't seem to have anything called "Color mode" in "Printer Options", as per this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/21mJWjz.png)

Comment: I suspect you might be right regarding the driver-specific settings. (FWIW I only have one copy.)

Comment: @Sparhawk - `I don't think it's a general printing issue` - it still could be a driver problem, involving only those applications that, unlike Firefox, rely on the settings in the printer-driver-GUI.